# Using .qpt file in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer, qgis-modeler, template

I am trying to create a project and to make maps in that I have an specific template which is stored as a .qpt file. Now I want the data frames in the template to be changed using the Python code so that one by one maps can be created.

Is there any way so that I can create maps automatically?

Note: I had already tried atlas feature and it is not working for me .

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand your question: what python code? what do you want to do with graphical modeler? in which way did the atlas not work for you?

Comment: Sorry the question was a bit mixed up, I had to create multiple maps of a village dividing the village into grids and do some calculations on it and in order to do so i have created several graphical modular and in order to run those models one by one i had created a python code. the last step is to show the results as a map and all maps have a same template so i was hoping i can do this either by using a model or by python.

Comment: Precise your question : what kind of analysis do you run? Do you know atlas function in qgis composer?